# Codeigniter login_validation error

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

When I load the main page and try to leave the login details blank,I get page you requested is not found.This my code  main and login files resp. kindly help

```
<?php
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function members()
    {
        $this->load->view('members');
    }

    public function login_validation()
    {
        //do validation here,load validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //setting rules for input data
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            redirect('main/members');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use md5 for passwords not secure any more use this to create http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and this to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Are you saying that when you submit the login form and all the fields are empty that you get a 404 Page Not Found error? Does it work when you do fill in the fields?

Comment: Show the URLs being hit and the routes.php file.

Comment: By using "if($this->form_validation->run())" you are just saying if it runs.  In the future try it this way "if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {"what to do if rules are not met} else {What to do if rules are met}

Answer (score 1):

This means your login.php view does not exist.

Answer (score -2):

You should check your view folder to see if login.php exist there.